# How would I remove a sector/slice from a 2D numpy (lat,lon) array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geometry

I have a two-dimensional array of mesh-grided (lat,lon) data in a numpy array. From a single specified point in this array, I want to extend two lines in different directions, such that the area between these two lines creates the sector of a circle. This is best explained in the visualisation below:

[image]

The numbers in the image have no meaning, they're just for visualisation.

I wish to convert all the points within the sector to NaN values, such that the indices of the red zeros can be captured. (In the image it was easier to draw these as red zeros, but NaNs are preferable. It's really their index that I'm after.) The inputs to this will be the array, the centerpoint of the arc, and and the angles of each line relative to the horizontal (or vertical). The lines should extend beyond the edge of the (lat,lon) region, as in the diagram.

Can anyone suggest a way to get me started, and which numpy routines would be most helpful? I'm admittedly a little stumped.

EDIT: I also have a matching array of meshgridded latitudes and mesgridded longitudes. The integer index of the centrepoint is known (since I know the lat/lon of the centerpoint). "Angles" and "lines" in this context refer to literal geographic space.

Comment: The problem is not well-defined. To convert array items to anything, you need the integer indexes of the items. What is your formula for calculating such indexes?

Comment: The text is confusing. Would it help you to know how to check if a point is in a polygon (the triangle)? If yes, is shapely an option :-)

Comment: Martin, yes I'm sure that would be helpful! I suppose I could test each point individually for whether it is contained by the triangle/arc.

Comment: How large might be your arc (e.g. 45, 90, 180 degrees) ?

Comment: MBo, the size of the arc would theoretically be specifiable, but go ahead and choose an arbitrary arc size if that helps you solve the problem. I'm sure I could generalise this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let you have central indexes `cx, cy`

Precalculate values for starting and ending angles of the sector:

```
  S_Cos = Cos(Start)
  S_Sin = Sin(Start)
  E_Cos = Cos(End)
  E_Sin = Sin(End)
```

And make [floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) with zeros using border conditions:

```
 (x-cx) * S_Sin - (y-cy) * S_Cos >= 0   //point is left to starting ray
 (x-cx) * E_Sin - (y-cy) * E_Cos <= 0   //point is right to ending ray
 x >= minx, y>=miny, x<=maxx, y<=maxy   //coordinate is inside array
```

---

Former approach:

For small arc angles (< 90 degrees):

Choose filling direction  - for most cases horizontal line is good choice, while for some start/end directions vertical filling is more convenient (for example: 350 degrees - 10 degrees)

Make traversal along rays from the center using [Bresenham line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm). For each Y-step fill with zeros horizontal line between rays or between ray and rectangle (array) border

For larger arc - divide arc into some smaller by OX, OY axes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Admittedly I needed some time to understand this answer, but yep, works great. I used the first approach. :)